# Adding contentDescription to list of TextView

Tags: android

I am trying to figure out how to add a contentDescription to a ListView, as it is being populated. I look at an answer but wasn't sure how to implement it. Here is my code:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    drawerLayout=(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    drawerListener = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, 
            R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close){

        public void onDrawerOpen(View drawerView){

            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }

        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView){

            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }
    };

    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerListener);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    planets=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets);  //get planets array
    listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawerList);

    //Set ArrayAdapter
    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, planets ));

    //set onClickListener for array
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
```

thanks;

Comment: You could use the ArrayAdapter's getItem method to get the item at each position. Check the instance of this item and if it is of type TextView, go ahead with setting the content description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArrayAdapter doesn't do it. You'll have to extend it, like this:

replace with `listView.setAdapter(...` with:

```
listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, planets ){

    @Override
    public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
       v.setContentDescription(... value ...);
       return v;
    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you, that was excellent answer but I thought I knew how to the combine the "button" string and the text for each item. It failed, could you provide a way to do this and point me in the right direction. It should say for example "Mercury button". thanks again